# Pandas Time Series DataFrame Missing Values

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, time-series, forecasting

I have a dataset of *Total Sales* from 2008-2015. I have an entry for each day, and so I have a created a pandas `DataFrame` with a `DatetimeIndex` and a column for sales. So it looks like this[image]

The problem is that I am missing data for most of 2010. These missing values are currently represented by `0.0` so if I plot the DataFrame I get

[image]

I want to try forecast values for 2016, possibly using an *ARIMA* model, so the first step I took was to perform a decomposition of this time series

[image]

Obviously if I leave 2010 in the DataFrame any attempted prediction will be skewed by the apparent, albeit erroneous, drop in sales.

What is the recommended approach in this situation? I think I should just drop 2010 altogether, but then I don't know if my time series is valid going from 2009 to 2011. I don't want to fill the missing values, because I don't believe I can do so accurately.

If I just delete 2010, however, the plot 'fills in' 2010 which doesn't help me

```
sales = sales.drop(sales['2010'].index)
```

[image]

Comment: Your question is a better fit at CrossValidated (http://stats.stackexchange.com), though searching for "time series missing data" there might give you the answer.

Comment: I think dropping 2010 as of beeing incomplete is a good idea. Then you can not plot/forecast based on the timestamp/date as your last figure shows. Yet you can easily plot/forecast using the index of each entry, but label the baseline with each associated date. 
Thus the date will be visible, yet no hole will result from dropping 2010.