# Pandas: Plotting a time series even when missing values

Tags: pandas, dataframe, time-series, pandas-groupby, missing-data

I have data sets that are series of events with timestamp. I want to plot the number of events that occur at every time interval (several plots, such as, "every month" or "every day" or "every hour"). These plots are built using `pandas`, in particular `groupby()`

I have figured out how to do this, however the plots omit the ranges of date for which **there are no events**. For instance, in the example below, there is no event on 2020-08-16, so that date is not plotted. **Instead, I would like it to be plotted with a count of 0.**

I know how to do this the old hacky way: I can post-process this data myself using Python loops, etc.. But this sounds like something that `pandas` should be able to do more efficiently, however I am not able to figure out how.

I have created a minimal reproducible code snippet:
https://gist.github.com/jlumbroso/50afaa12d8af8dac615331d515f0f0ff

And provided an illustrative example here:

```
0   2020-08-15 16:34:15.838169  False
1   2020-08-17 14:25:08.778913  True
2   2020-08-19 07:44:07.514456  False
3   2020-08-19 14:48:29.160890  True
4   2020-08-20 03:26:00.479444  False
5   2020-08-20 10:57:52.904366  False
6   2020-08-20 19:17:45.079390  True
7   2020-08-20 23:38:41.369156  False
8   2020-08-21 12:21:54.340702  True
9   2020-08-24 19:42:13.458472  False
10  2020-08-24 23:09:39.369394  True
11  2020-08-25 16:35:05.059722  False
12  2020-08-26 01:31:29.243435  True
13  2020-08-26 03:28:25.418322  True
14  2020-08-27 12:42:43.905486  True
15  2020-08-31 10:35:57.143843  False
16  2020-09-02 11:32:54.219081  True
17  2020-09-02 14:07:05.544261  False
18  2020-09-03 08:05:32.133082  False
19  2020-09-10 15:28:46.725916  True
20  2020-09-12 00:57:58.558055  True
21  2020-09-13 21:28:02.450837  True
```

[image: Example plot]

I found these related questions but I was not able to infer an answer from them:

- [Pandas Time Series DataFrame Missing Values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38119601/pandas-time-series-dataframe-missing-values)
- [pandas plot time-series with minimized gaps](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38572534/pandas-plot-time-series-with-minimized-gaps)
- [Pandas Resampling error: Only valid with DatetimeIndex or PeriodIndex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30857680/pandas-resampling-error-only-valid-with-datetimeindex-or-periodindex)
- [Groupby and resample timeseries so date ranges are consistent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50273308/groupby-and-resample-timeseries-so-date-ranges-are-consistent)

Thanks for any help!

Comment: This may help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63421569/making-a-timeseries-plot-in-python-but-want-to-skip-few-months/63421961#63421961

Comment: Thank you @Richard but unfortunately that does not help. I think part of my problem is that the `groupby()` transforms the data frame and I am not sure how to plugin to other solutions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, you need to use [Resample](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.resample.html).
Let's use your data

```
content = """0   2020-08-15 16:34:15.838169  False
1   2020-08-17 14:25:08.778913  True
2   2020-08-19 07:44:07.514456  False
3   2020-08-19 14:48:29.160890  True
4   2020-08-20 03:26:00.479444  False
5   2020-08-20 10:57:52.904366  False
6   2020-08-20 19:17:45.079390  True
7   2020-08-20 23:38:41.369156  False
8   2020-08-21 12:21:54.340702  True
9   2020-08-24 19:42:13.458472  False
10  2020-08-24 23:09:39.369394  True
11  2020-08-25 16:35:05.059722  False
12  2020-08-26 01:31:29.243435  True
13  2020-08-26 03:28:25.418322  True
14  2020-08-27 12:42:43.905486  True
15  2020-08-31 10:35:57.143843  False
16  2020-09-02 11:32:54.219081  True
17  2020-09-02 14:07:05.544261  False
18  2020-09-03 08:05:32.133082  False
19  2020-09-10 15:28:46.725916  True
20  2020-09-12 00:57:58.558055  True
21  2020-09-13 21:28:02.450837  True
"""
from io import StringIO
df = pd.read_csv(StringIO(content), sep="  ", header=None, index_col=0)
print(df)
                              1      2
0                                     
0    2020-08-15 16:34:15.838169  False
1    2020-08-17 14:25:08.778913   True
2    2020-08-19 07:44:07.514456  False
3    2020-08-19 14:48:29.160890   True
4    2020-08-20 03:26:00.479444  False
5    2020-08-20 10:57:52.904366  False
6    2020-08-20 19:17:45.079390   True
7    2020-08-20 23:38:41.369156  False
8    2020-08-21 12:21:54.340702   True
9    2020-08-24 19:42:13.458472  False
10   2020-08-24 23:09:39.369394   True
11   2020-08-25 16:35:05.059722  False
12   2020-08-26 01:31:29.243435   True
13   2020-08-26 03:28:25.418322   True
14   2020-08-27 12:42:43.905486   True
15   2020-08-31 10:35:57.143843  False
16   2020-09-02 11:32:54.219081   True
17   2020-09-02 14:07:05.544261  False
18   2020-09-03 08:05:32.133082  False
19   2020-09-10 15:28:46.725916   True
20   2020-09-12 00:57:58.558055   True
21   2020-09-13 21:28:02.450837   True
```

Use the first column like index, and then drop it:

```
df = df.set_index(pd.DatetimeIndex(df.iloc[:,0]))
df.drop(df.columns[0], 1, inplace=True)
df
    2
1   
2020-08-15 16:34:15.838169  False
2020-08-17 14:25:08.778913  True
2020-08-19 07:44:07.514456  False
2020-08-19 14:48:29.160890  True
2020-08-20 03:26:00.479444  False
2020-08-20 10:57:52.904366  False
2020-08-20 19:17:45.079390  True
2020-08-20 23:38:41.369156  False
2020-08-21 12:21:54.340702  True
2020-08-24 19:42:13.458472  False
2020-08-24 23:09:39.369394  True
2020-08-25 16:35:05.059722  False
2020-08-26 01:31:29.243435  True
2020-08-26 03:28:25.418322  True
2020-08-27 12:42:43.905486  True
2020-08-31 10:35:57.143843  False
2020-09-02 11:32:54.219081  True
2020-09-02 14:07:05.544261  False
2020-09-03 08:05:32.133082  False
2020-09-10 15:28:46.725916  True
2020-09-12 00:57:58.558055  True
2020-09-13 21:28:02.450837  True
```

**Resample by, for example, day**, sum, and plot

```
df.resample('D').sum().plot()
```

[image: image1]

Note that is usefull if you have columns names:

```
content = """Date  Condition
0   2020-08-15 16:34:15.838169  False
1   2020-08-17 14:25:08.778913  True
2   2020-08-19 07:44:07.514456  False
3   2020-08-19 14:48:29.160890  True
4   2020-08-20 03:26:00.479444  False
5   2020-08-20 10:57:52.904366  False
6   2020-08-20 19:17:45.079390  True
7   2020-08-20 23:38:41.369156  False
8   2020-08-21 12:21:54.340702  True
9   2020-08-24 19:42:13.458472  False
10  2020-08-24 23:09:39.369394  True
11  2020-08-25 16:35:05.059722  False
12  2020-08-26 01:31:29.243435  True
13  2020-08-26 03:28:25.418322  True
14  2020-08-27 12:42:43.905486  True
15  2020-08-31 10:35:57.143843  False
16  2020-09-02 11:32:54.219081  True
17  2020-09-02 14:07:05.544261  False
18  2020-09-03 08:05:32.133082  False
19  2020-09-10 15:28:46.725916  True
20  2020-09-12 00:57:58.558055  True
21  2020-09-13 21:28:02.450837  True
"""
from io import StringIO
df = pd.read_csv(StringIO(content), sep="  ", index_col=0)
print(df)
                           Date  Condition
0    2020-08-15 16:34:15.838169      False
1    2020-08-17 14:25:08.778913       True
2    2020-08-19 07:44:07.514456      False
3    2020-08-19 14:48:29.160890       True
4    2020-08-20 03:26:00.479444      False
5    2020-08-20 10:57:52.904366      False
6    2020-08-20 19:17:45.079390       True
7    2020-08-20 23:38:41.369156      False
8    2020-08-21 12:21:54.340702       True
9    2020-08-24 19:42:13.458472      False
10   2020-08-24 23:09:39.369394       True
11   2020-08-25 16:35:05.059722      False
12   2020-08-26 01:31:29.243435       True
13   2020-08-26 03:28:25.418322       True
14   2020-08-27 12:42:43.905486       True
15   2020-08-31 10:35:57.143843      False
16   2020-09-02 11:32:54.219081       True
17   2020-09-02 14:07:05.544261      False
18   2020-09-03 08:05:32.133082      False
19   2020-09-10 15:28:46.725916       True
20   2020-09-12 00:57:58.558055       True
21   2020-09-13 21:28:02.450837       True
```

and

```
df = df.set_index(pd.DatetimeIndex(df['Date']))
df.drop(["Date"], 1, inplace=True)
df
Condition
Date    
2020-08-15 16:34:15.838169  False
2020-08-17 14:25:08.778913  True
2020-08-19 07:44:07.514456  False
2020-08-19 14:48:29.160890  True
2020-08-20 03:26:00.479444  False
2020-08-20 10:57:52.904366  False
2020-08-20 19:17:45.079390  True
2020-08-20 23:38:41.369156  False
2020-08-21 12:21:54.340702  True
2020-08-24 19:42:13.458472  False
2020-08-24 23:09:39.369394  True
2020-08-25 16:35:05.059722  False
2020-08-26 01:31:29.243435  True
2020-08-26 03:28:25.418322  True
2020-08-27 12:42:43.905486  True
2020-08-31 10:35:57.143843  False
2020-09-02 11:32:54.219081  True
2020-09-02 14:07:05.544261  False
2020-09-03 08:05:32.133082  False
2020-09-10 15:28:46.725916  True
2020-09-12 00:57:58.558055  True
2020-09-13 21:28:02.450837  True
df.resample('D').sum().plot()
```

[image: second]

Comment: Thank you very much @Richard. I am curious: Why do you drop the column after setting it as index?

Comment: I will add another answer, here I cann't format code.

Answer (score 0):

**Q**: Why do you drop the column after setting it as index?
**A**: Because before that you have the column twice, like an index and like a dimension/attribute/data:

```
                            Date                    Condition
Date        
2020-08-15 16:34:15.838169  2020-08-15 16:34:15.838169  False
2020-08-17 14:25:08.778913  2020-08-17 14:25:08.778913  True
2020-08-19 07:44:07.514456  2020-08-19 07:44:07.514456  False
2020-08-19 14:48:29.160890  2020-08-19 14:48:29.160890  True
2020-08-20 03:26:00.479444  2020-08-20 03:26:00.479444  False
2020-08-20 10:57:52.904366  2020-08-20 10:57:52.904366  False
```